# Get maximum of sequence

Tags: sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

```
+----+-------+
| id | value | 
+----+-------+
|  1 |    A  |
|  2 |    B  |
|  3 |    C  |
|  4 |    D  |
|  5 |    D  |
|  6 |    D  |
|  7 |    N  |
|  8 |    P  |
|  9 |    P  |
+----+-------+
```

Desired output

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | value |      calc ↓         |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |    A  |          1          |
|  2 |    B  |          2          |
|  3 |    C  |          3          |
|  4 |    D  |          6          |
|  5 |    D  |          6          |
|  6 |    D  |          6          |
|  7 |    N  |          7          |
|  8 |    P  |          9          |
|  9 |    P  |          9          |
| 10 |    D  |          11         |
| 11 |    D  |          11         |
| 12 |    Z  |          12         |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

Can you help me for a solution for this ? Id is identity, id must be present in output, must have the same 9 rows in output.

New note: I added rows 10,11,12. Notice that id 10 and 11 which has letter 'D' is in a different group from id 4,5,6

thanks

Comment: Hint: `MAX() OVER()`. Please tag your question with the DBMS you're using eg: SQL Srever, MySQL, Oracle ..

Comment: Unclear to me why one part of the question asks for 9 rows in the result set and another part shows 12 rows.  Three additional rows have been added and it is quite unclear what they mean.  My recommendation is that you ask a new question, be clear on what you want, and dd an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grouping also depends on the surrounding ids then this turns into something like the gaps and islands problem [https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/#:~:text=The%20SQL%20of%20Gaps%20and%20Islands%20in%20Sequences,...%204%20Performance%20Comparison%20of%20Gaps%20Solutions.%20](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20of%20Gaps%20and%20Islands%20in%20Sequences,...%204%20Performance%20Comparison%20of%20Gaps%20Solutions.%20)

You could use the Tabibitosan method https://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html

Here you also need to group by your value column but that doesn't complicate it too much:

```
select id, value, max(id) over (partition by value, island) calc
from (
select id, value, id - row_number() over(partition by value order by id) island
from my_table
) as sq
order by id;
```

The `id - row_number() over(partition by value order by id)` expression gives you a number which changes each time the ID value changes by more than 1 for each value of value. This gets included in the `max(id) over (partition by value, island)` expression. The island number is only valid for that particular value. In your case, both values N and D have a computed island number of 6 but they need to be considered differently.

Db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jahP7T6xBt3cpbLRhZZdQG/1

Answer (score 1):

For this sample date you need MAX() window function:

```
SELECT id, value,
       MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY value) calc
FROM tablename
```

Comment: New note: I added rows 10,11,12. Notice that id 10 and 11 which has letter 'D' is in a different group from id 4,5,6

Comment: @lozin this code answers the question as you posted it. If your requirement is different you can post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, value, (SELECT max(id) FROM TABLE inner where inner.value = outer.value)
FROM table as outer
```

Comment: New note: I added rows 10,11,12. Notice that id 10 and 11 which has letter 'D' is in a different group from id 4,5,6